# JMeter - Convert Random URL-safe string can be into Base64 URL-encoded SHA-256 hash

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, sha, beanshell, jsr223

I have a code verifier which is a random string of 43 characters ,thatI need to convert into Base64 URL-encoded SHA-256 hash and then need to pass as a request parameters

How can I achieve that in JMeter TOOL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 functions [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) to get random string of 43 characters

And then [digest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest)

```
${__digest(SHA-256,${__RandomString(43)},,,)}
```

Comment: Using this method, it is not giving the expected value This is a randoom 43 character string(code verifier) : 
M25iVXpKU3puUjFaYWg3T1NDTDQtcW1ROUY5YXlwalNoc0hhakxifmZHag


After using this function,it gives aa3af3496f60322520a54bea8043c4e3ffbcb30bf20ad7ce56f839e68e52fdeb

But expected value is qjrzSW9gMiUgpUvqgEPE4_-8swvyCtfOVvg55o5S_es

I believe it gives value in HEX but I need in binary. So how can I get this expected value ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is already given by user7294900, just add base64encode method as below:

```
${__base64Encode(${__digest(SHA-256,${__RandomString(43,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)},,,)},)}
```

---

**MY 2 CENTS**

JMeter has below 3 in-built functions for your purpose:

1. base64Encode -> ${__base64Encode(,)}
2. digest -> ${__digest(,,,,)}
3. RandomString -> ${__RandomString(,,)}

All these are accessible from function helper

[image]

**You can use them in any order:**

1. Generate Random String -> Encode it with SHA 256 -> Encode SHA 256 output with Base 64
2. Generate Random String -> Encode it with Base 64 -> Encode base 64 output with SHA 256

Examples:

For 1st Order

```
${__base64Encode(${__digest(SHA-256,${__RandomString(43,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)},,,)},)}
```

For 2nd Order

```
${__digest(SHA-256,${__base64Encode(${__RandomString(43,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)},)},,,)}
```

**Quirks about the functions:**

1. Make sure to explicitly provide the necessary characters that have to be used for RandomString generation. Else it will literally generate random string which might not be "String" per-se
2. Digest needs inputs only in a specific format as defined below:

> MD2
>   MD5
>   SHA-1
>   SHA-224
>   SHA-256
>   SHA-384
>   SHA-512

Source: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest

Also if you need to reuse this value across in different requests then be sure to store it in a variable name. You should be able to see that option when you use the function helper.

---

Hope this helps!